# SetInterval with different interval in middle

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

This is my code currently:

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    if ( i != 3 ) {
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
        ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' )
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
            document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
            ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' )          
        }, 10000);
    }
    i++
}, 1000);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that every second it takes removes 'hide' class from div. Now this part work.

But what I also would like to add is that we are on 3rd div (i=3), the timeout would be actually 10 seconds and the whole intervall/thing would pause for that 10 seconds time. Basically meaning it would show 3rd div for 10 seconds, pause the interval and remove hide class (yeah, class naming actually should be show) for 3rd div and then continue again with all the other divs showing for 1 second. Now it basically skips the 3rd div since intervall overrides settimetout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keypoint is about closure.

With this code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
        ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' )          
    }, 10000);
```

You think `i` inside it will be `3`, but it's not.

**The solution is:**

```
function handle(i) {
   setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
        ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' )          
    }, 10000);
};
```

and your code will be:

```
var i = 1;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    doSomething();
    if (i === 3) {
        doOtherthing(i);
    }
}, 1000);

function doSomething() {
    // do something

    i++;
}

function doOtherthing(tmp) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do something

        i++;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            doSomething();
            if (i > 10) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, 10000);
};
```

refer http://jsfiddle.net/creeper/pka43o5c/1/

Comment: Hmm, it still behaves same way. It doesn't show the 3rd div. Or well it will after 10sec, but because it should pause the interval for 10sec too.

Comment: This is an example I wrote to test, and everything is okay. http://jsfiddle.net/creeper/pka43o5c/

Comment: Yes, maybe I wrote badly what I was after. The whole thing should stop for 10 seconds when it's the 3rd point. Now it goes 4th, 5th etc. and 3rd comes after 10 seconds and the order is wrong. The order should stay same, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.. only at 3rd point it should have 10 second pause.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a chain of `setTimeout`s instead of `setInterval`s here:

```
var i = 1;
setTimeout(function tOutFunc() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
        document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
        ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' )          
    }, i == 3 ? 10000 : 1000);
    i++
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with a recursive `setTimeout`:

```
var i = 1;
function showBoxes() {
    if(i === 2 ) {
        console.log(i)
        setTimeout(showBoxes, 10000)
        removeClass(i)
    }
    else if(i <= 5) {
        console.log(i)
        setTimeout(showBoxes, 1000)
        removeClass(i)
    }
    ++i;
}

function removeClass(i){
    document.getElementById("box-" + i).className =
    document.getElementById("box-" + i).className.replace
    ( /(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '' );
}

setTimeout(showBoxes, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzh2Lygf/